# Why am I getting accuracy of Xgboost model 0.00%?

Tags: deep-learning, xgboost

I am trying to build Job Recommender System using Deep Learning.

[dataset used](https://www.kaggle.com/c/job-recommendation/data)
From this dataset i have taken only users.tsv, user_history.tsv, apps.tsv and jobs.tsv to build a hybrid recommender system.

The steps i have performed till now are:

1. One hot encoding on this dataset
2. Embedding on one hot encoded features to reduce dimension and sparsity
3. Concatenated all the 4 datasets(Embedded matrix and non-categorical features of dataset)
4. Created Xgboost model for feature regularization

But I am getting accuracy of xgboost model equal to 0.00%. After this i also need to perform CNN to get the top-k recommendations, but since i am getting accuracy of xgboost model zero i cannot proceed further. So, please help me.

Google drive URL to my code:
[code URL](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19oKUrJo0xU82ozGrY3rrnLxVwPB8nKSy)

Comment: Without the code, we will never know what you did? And one hot encoding and then Embedding??

Comment: Obviously, we cannot say anything without looking at the code... Apart from that, please read [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/one-hot-encoding-is-making-your-tree-based-ensembles-worse-heres-why-d64b282b5769) article about why you do not want to use one hot encoding with tree-based algorithms.

Comment: Sorry, but now i have shared google drive link to my code in the description above. Please have a look at it.  Reason for doing one hot encoding and embedding is i am trying to implement one Research Paper (which is also available on my drive) and i am completely new to this field so, Thank you